# VSS 2005 issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working on a project with VS2010 and VSS 2005 for 3 months now. Usually I use command Gel latest from VS2010 and I get updated code files. Today since there was some issue in getting latest file I used Get latest command from VSS directly, attached screenshot with options I selected while getting latest.[image]

After this my code is not compiling at all hundreds of errors coming. Since the errors are related with permission I manually removed 'Read Only' attribute of Bin and Obj folders and then my code compiled, no error. But then VS2010 doesn't prompt out nor check out files if I do any changes in the code files.

How to resolve this?

> Error 156 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\BusinessObjects.dll" to "bin\Debug\BusinessObjects.dll". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\BusinessObjects.dll' is denied.   Business Objects

Comment: *Shudder* SourceSafe, where your code **isn't** safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you accidentally checked in your bin and/or obj folder. Since VSS would like to make these readonly, it interferes with the build-- also as other team members check in recently built obj and binariaries, and you go get them (on get latest) they can break your build in your working folder. There is probably more than one way do it, but you can remove the obj and bin artifacts directly from VSS then check out to a new working folder, then add .dll, etc, to the ignore list.

Or it is something else.

Comment: I deleted all bin and obj folder from VSS as well as from local physical location and it worked.